# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException error trying to identify element to click using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

despite numerous tries I'm unable to perform the following action(s).

I need to land on a page that contains one or more table rows/columns. For each (sequentially) I need to click on an arrow that opens a pop-up, close the window, then rinse and repeat.

**Problem**: I am unable to click on the item

**Error:**

> class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'

**Snippet of code that prompts the error:**

```
[...]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")


    # MODIFY URL HERE
    driver.get(url)
[..]
try:
        # arf = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_d_dettaglio_ctl02_button1").click()
        arf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_d_dettaglio_ctl02_button1"]').click()
        pprint.pprint(arf)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("error!", NoSuchElementException)
        driver.close()
        exit()
```

**HTML element I need to interact with:**

```
                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$d_dettaglio$ctl02$button1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_d_dettaglio_ctl02_button1" src="../images/spunta_maggiore.gif" style="height:22px;width:22px;border-width:0px;">
                        </td>
```

**Things I've tried:**

- `driver.find_element_by_xpath (//input[@id etc...]`) or `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name])`
- `driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_d_dettaglio_ctl02_button1").click()`
- `driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_d_dettaglio_ctl02_button1").click()`

In both cases, a no element found exception is raised.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to load? e.g. `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'xpath of your choice here'))).click()`

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='image'][name*='ContentPlaceHolder'][id*='d_dettaglio'][src*='images/spunta_maggiore']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@name, 'ContentPlaceHolder') and contains(@id, 'd_dettaglio')][@type='image' and contains(@src, 'images/spunta_maggiore.gif')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)